# Are sequences going to +infty along a ultrafilter on $\omega$ essentialy increasing?

Tags: ultrafilters

The question is essentially in the title: suppose you have a non-principal ultrafilter $p$ on $\omega$ and a sequence $(u_n)_{n\in \omega}$ of elements of $\omega$ such that the $p$-limit of $(u_n)$ is $+\infty$.
Does it exist a set $I\in p$ such that the sequence is monotonous increasing when restricted to $I$: for all $i<j$ in $I$, we have $u_i\leq u_j$?

I cannot think of a counterexample, but any try of proof ends somehow with an infinite intersection of elements of $p$, of which I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To obtain an ultrafilter that doesn't have the property in question, begin by partitioning $\omega$ into infinitely many infinite subsets $A_k$ ($k\in\omega$) and choosing a nonprincipal ultrafilter $U_k$ on $A_k$ for each $k$. Also choose another nonprincipal ultrafilter $V$ on $\omega$, and define
$$
W=\{X\subseteq\omega:\{k:X\cap A_k\in U_k\}\in V\}.
$$
This $W$ is nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega$. For each $n\in\omega$, let $u_n$ be the $k$ such that $n\in A_k$. Then $u_n$ approaches $\infty$ along $W$ (essentially because $V$ is nonprincipal), but, for any $I\in W$, the subsequence $(u_n)_{n\in I}$ repeats values infinitely often (and therefore also strictly decreases infinitely often).

Unless  I've overlooked something, the property in the question is equivalent to selectivity of the ultrafilter.  Selective ultrafilters cannot be proved to exist in ZFC, but can be proved to exist under additional (consistent) hypotheses, such as the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: I think I see why the ultrafilter $p$ must be selective. To see that it's a P-point, given a partition of $\omega$ into sets $A_k\notin p$, I consider a function $f:\omega\to\omega$ which is constant on each $A_k$. To see that it's a Q-point, given a partition of $\omega$ into nonempty finite sets $A_k$, I consider an injection $f:\omega\to\omega$ which is strictly decreasing on each $A_k$. Is this correct? Is this how you show it, or do you have a better way?

Comment: @bof Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!